# A secular version of fate/destiny?

Tags: single-word-requests, idiom-requests, phrase-requests, proverb-requests

The Wikipedia page for [destiny](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Destiny) states:

> Destiny, sometimes referred to as fate (from Latin fatum – destiny), is a predetermined course of events. It may be conceived as a predetermined future, whether in general or of an individual.

Both destiny and fate are usually used in a more religious or superstitious senses.

Originally, I thought of words like *coincidental* or *happenstance* but they kind of lack the absurdness of the situation.

For interpersonal relationships *birds of a feather flock together* is pretty spot-on, but also quite a mouthful.

Any ideas?

Comment: Especially after reading lots of science fiction and fantasy, I've never taken it to be meant in a religious or superstitious sense.

Comment: @JasonBassford Sure, but there are certainly sensibilities that might be worth avoiding if possible.

Comment: I think you're reading too much into it. (The definitions themselves don't even imply such a link.)

Comment: Interesting question. I see your Wikipedia entry says "predetermined future", what was wrong with using that?

Comment: Maybe [determinism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinism)

Comment: What do you want this replacement to mean? What 'situation' are you referring too and how is it absurd? (I feel you are leaving out a bigger story) If we don't know that, then we're just guessing wildly. Check out a thesaurus and tell us why those words don't fit the situation for you  (in addition to telling us the situation).

Comment: *Fate* and *destiny* are already secular. The religious version is *God's will*.

Answer (score 5):

Neither fate nor destiny are necessarily associated with religion or superstition.  However if you don't like the words there are alternatives.

None of the alternative you suggest are appropriate. 'Coincidence' or 'happenstance' mean the opposite of destiny, implying that whatever happened happened by chance, whereas 'destiny' and 'fate' implies that no chance is involved.

'birds of a feather flock together' simply means that similar people (or occasionally things) tend to associate with one another. It has nothing to do with destiny or chance, whether in interpersonal relationships or otherwise.

Alternatives to 'destiny' might include 'predestination', 'predetermination' or 'inevitability'.

Answer (score 0):

I  propose the use of the word **fortune**.

This word is stated as

> 1. the turns and courses of luck accompanying one's progress (as through
>    life)
> 2. chance or luck as an external, arbitrary force affecting human affairs

Such examples of this word include, but are not limited to:

> 1. She must smile upon **fortune** that she found her way back to her family.
> 2. He was jealous of his neighbor's good **fortune**.

It is a single word holding no religious annotation, and seems to fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Serendipity seems to convey the sense of a fortuitous coincidence without implying some kind of divine providence.

Answer (score -1):

How about the 2nd or 3rd definitions of concurrence (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/concurrence):

2 : a coincidence of equal powers in law

3 a : the simultaneous occurrence of events or circumstances ·The concurrence of heavy rain and strong winds delayed the plane's departure.

And there is always the tried and true 'twist of fate'. EBT

Answer (score -2):

I vote for "future realities". It allows for infinite possibilities, randomly generated, in any universe(s) one chooses - an unknown intellectual thought experiment.

Comment: scored -1 again.